# celery tasks: update state after try & except block

Tags: django, rabbitmq, task, celery, flower

I have celery 4.1.0, django 1.11.11, rabbitMQ and Redis for results.

```
@shared_task(bind=True)
    def one_task(self):
        try:
            ...
            some db stuff here
            ...
        except BaseException as error:
            self.update_state(state='FAILURE', 
                              meta={'notes': 'some notes'})
            logger.error('Error Message ', exc_info=True, 
                         extra={'error': error})
```

So, when my code runs into except block self.update_state does not work but logger works...
Actually, I'm not sure if

```
@shared_task(bin=True)
```

it's right...

What I want to do it's catch exceptions(through try & except blocks) of my python code, change states and terminate the tasks manually. 
So, any advise/help?

Comment: What do you mean by saying that it is not working?

Comment: Well, when I look in my flower dashboard, my task finish with success state :/

Answer (score 1):

Celery will set success status on every task that finished without throwing an exception. And you're catching that exception without throwing it back.

Unfortunately, throwing it won't help, because celery will put task into failed state with its own error message.

Only solution to that problem is to set `ignore_result=True` option on this task, so celery won't manage state of this task, but celery documentation suggests that it may have other side effects.